# MySQLからロードした日本語の文字情報をクライアントで表示できない

Tags: linux, mysql, teraterm

利用端末 TeraTerm 4.103
MySQL 5.6.10

TeraTerm 端末設定
コーディング受信、コーディング送信 = UTF-8
ロケール： american <= あまり影響ないと思います。
[image: TeraTerm端末設定]

設定はUTF8です。
UTF8エンコーディングあるファイルは`source`コマンドで実行時、正常に実行できますが、selectを実行時日本語がある情報は???を示します。

```
mysql>  show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                            |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                             |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                             |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                           |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                           |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                             |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                           |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                             |
| character_sets_dir       | 。。。。 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

別のstackoverflowのpost確認時、２つ対応方法を試し見ましたが、文字化け文字を残ります。

対応１：

```
set names utf8;
```

対応２：
クライアント実行時、デフォルト文字コードを指定

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8
```

或いは

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

参照：
[MySQL command line formatting with UTF8 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787824/mysql-command-line-formatting-with-utf8)

他の方法がないですか？ちなみに、OS(Linux)の文字コードはUTF8です。

============================================

補足情報

システム言語値：

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-16-0-53 ~]$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
[ec2-user@ip-10-16-0-53 ~]$ env | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

フォント設定

フォント名：Terminal
フォントStype：Regular
フォントサイズ：9
Script: OEM/DOS

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

※解決できましたが、原因分からない、もし他人同じ問題があるため、補足情報追加

最初インストールしたのTeraTermはWindows Installer型はProgram Files (x86)ディレクトりにインストールします。このTeraTermは日本語示すできません。

https://osdn.net/projects/ttssh2/downloads/71232/teraterm-4.103.exe/

も一回RC版の圧縮ZIPファイル型のTeraTermダウンロードして、解凍し、今回のTeraTermは日本語表示できます。

https://osdn.net/projects/ttssh2/downloads/71210/teraterm-4.103-RC2.zip/

teraterm-4.103.exe vs teraterm-4.103-RC2.zipはどの違いがわかりません。多分Program Filesでインストール影響がある、原因調査します。

Comment: サーバ側の`echo $LANG`か、`env | grep LANG`の実行結果を教えてください。あとは……TeraTermのフォント設定も知りたいですかね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tera Termでロケールが"american"だと、
"言語コード(P)"はこうなっているのでは？[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここの "言語コード(P)" を`932`に変更したらいかがでしょう？

---

**追記**

自分のTeraTermのフォント設定は以下の通りです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

文字セットで日本語が使えないフォントだと表示できないと思います。

Comment: TeraTerm v4.103（最新版）場合言語コードの設定から除く。質問の設定ファイルを参照↑↑↑

Comment: 言語コードとロケールは紐づいているので、その場合は`japanese`をロケールに入力してください。

Comment: japaneseに設定して、だた情報は？じゃなくて、文字化けになった。

Comment: どのような状態になったか質問に追記できますでしょうか？恐らく`932`(Shift-JIS)が何らかの原因で表示できないか、サーバ側の文字が無理にShift-JISへ変換されているかだと思うのですが…。

Comment: 原因はわからないが、同じのTeraTerm v4.103はインストーラ型じゃない（圧縮ZIPファイル）再ダウンロードしたら、当TeraTermはうまく日本語情報表示できます。今回は私のパソコン２個TeraTermインストールしてしまう。何か違いわからない。Installer (WinInstall)場合、Windows10のElevation権限だけ違うと思われます。 Program Filesのディレクトリ。。。